# How to show selected value in select box inside table which is created dynamically from php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a table in php dynamically and with the ajax request I am appending this table row to the table body.

The table row contains selectbox and when the table is rendered the select box should have selected value in it.

I have tried it but it does not give output as selected,  it renders only `selected` the table row.

`Html table`

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
            <th>#Sl</th>
            <th width="20%">Name</th>
            <th width="15%">Schedule</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_data">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`My code for table`

```
$output.="
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='name_'.$count.'' name='name[]' maxlength='255' placeholder='Name' class='form-control' value='".$row['name']."'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id='schedule_'.$count.'' name='schedule[]' class='form-control'>
                <option value='Once Daily' ".($row['schedule']=='Once Daily')?'selected':''.">Once Daily</option>
                <option value='Twice Daily' ".($row['schedule']=='Twice Daily')?'selected':''.">Twice Daily</option>
                <option value='Thrice Daily' ".($row['schedule']=='Thrice Daily')?'selected':''.">Thrice Daily</option>
                <option value='Weekly Once' ".($row['schedule']=='Weekly Once')?'selected':''.">Weekly Once</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>"; 

    return $output;
```

`Ajax success response to append table`

```
$('#table_data').append(data.output)
```

Comment: You need to check the generated source code. You're using a double-quoted string, which means you can insert variables directly, without the `.` concatenation operator. Here's one way: https://ideone.com/c0cSLK

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the link. It really helped me.